# MySql Stored Procedure not compiling

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SearchProduct(
    
    IN Search VARCHAR(1000),
    IN OrderBy Varchar(100),
    In FromId varchar(10),
    In ToId varchar(10)
    
    )

BEGIN

Set @MQuery= '
 with DataTable as (

    SELECT Product.Id as ProductId, 
           Category.Id as CategoryId,
           Product.Active,
           Product.Name as ProductName,
           Catgeory.Name as CategoryName,
           Product.AddedOn,
           Product.AddedBy as UserId, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by '+ OrderBy  +') RowNumber,
    Count(*) OVER() as TotalRecords 
    
    FROM Product
    inner join ProductCategory 
    on Product.Id=ProductCategory.ProductId
    inner join Category 
    on Category.Id= ProductCategory.CategoryId

WHERE ' + Search+ ' ) '+

'
Select DataTable.*, (User.FirstName+space(1) + User.LastName) as FullName

from DataTable 
inner join User on DataTable.UserId= User.Id
where DataTable.RownNumber berween '+FromId +' and '+ ToId
+ ' order by DataTable.RowNumber'

execute @MQuery;

 END //
 
DELIMITER ;
```

Results in the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'execute @MQuery;
>
> END' at line 17

Comment: You probably need a `;` delimiter after the `' order by DataTable.RowNumber'` to terminate the `SET` statement.

Comment: You are using CTE,so it wont work on mysql.Maybe you mean sql server?

Comment: ok .. Actually I generally use this stored procedure in Sql  server but these days am working on mysql so need similar type of query in Mysql

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to concatenate strings in MySQL is using the function `concat()`.  The correct way to execute them is with `prepare`/`exec`.

And, there is no `with` statement in MySQL.  The statement you were trying to write is something like this:

```
Set @MQuery = concat('
 with DataTable as (

    SELECT Product.Id as ProductId, 
           Category.Id as CategoryId,
           Product.Active,
           Product.Name as ProductName,
           Catgeory.Name as CategoryName,
           Product.AddedOn,
           Product.AddedBy as UserId, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by '+ OrderBy  +') RowNumber,
    Count(*) OVER() as TotalRecords 

    FROM Product
    inner join ProductCategory 
    on Product.Id=ProductCategory.ProductId
    inner join Category 
    on Category.Id= ProductCategory.CategoryId

WHERE ', Search, ' ) ', 
'
Select DataTable.*, concat(User.FirstName, ' ', User.LastName) as FullName

from DataTable 
inner join User on DataTable.UserId= User.Id
where DataTable.RownNumber berween ', FromId, ' and ', ToId,
' order by DataTable.RowNumber' );

prepare stmt from @MQuery;

exec stmt;
```

This will probably compile, but you will have other problems.  You need to restructure the query for MySQL.  Clearly, you didn't try to run the query first before writing the stored procedure.  That's like going to gamble and putting all your money on the first game you play.  It might work, but not likely.

It looks like you were mixing MySQL and SQL Server syntax.

Comment: true...but can you help me to convert to Mysql

Comment: @ParulBansal . . . I would suggest that you ask this question separately and explicitly as a question (and leave out the stored procedure stuff).  Just get the query to work.  A SQL Fiddle would be very helpful for such a question.